# CSS change value

Tags: jquery, css

```
input[type=radio] {  
display: none; 
}

td::before {  
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 17px;  
    height: 17px;  
    border-radius: 8.5px;
    background-color: #005AA9; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<TD class="SP" onClick="SP_click(this);">
  <INPUT type=radio name="interaction.q1.a.answer" HIDEFOCUS="true" value="1" onClick="SP_set(this);" /><br>1
</TD>

<TD class="SP" onClick="SP_click(this);">
  <INPUT type=radio name="interaction.q1.a.answer" HIDEFOCUS="true" value="2" onClick="SP_set(this);" /><br>2
</TD>
```

The problem is -> html code is generated automatically by my software, so i can't change this. Can only do sth in css or add something in jquery

Comment: Where is html code?

Comment: html tags and all their attributes should be written all lower case!

Comment: @ZiemekPiątkowski can you post in answer as formatted code and remove the above? Also would recommend using lowercase for dom elements as such: `<td class="sp" onclick="sp_click(this);">` I also recommend no inline js,, and is the table really a table or a form? if it's a form look into `divs`

Answer (score 4):

```
input:checked {
    color: green;
}
```

jquery:

```
$(#myInput:checked).css("color", "green");
```

multiple CSS:

```
$(#myInput:checked).css({"color": "green", "background-color": "yellow"});
```